# Convert hexadecimal Shift-JIS to the characters

Tags: linux, unix, character-encoding, japanese

I am searching for the way to convert the hexadecimal value of Shift-JIS to the character in Unix/Linux command line.

A Shift-JIS code table [can be found here](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml).

For:

```
82 ae (0x82ae)
```

I would expect:

```
ぐ
```

I know it’s somehow possible with [`ascii2uni`](http://www.billposer.org/Software/ascii2uni_man.html) and [`nkf`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nkf1.html) but I’m kind of stuck.

**NOTE:** I could do this but it is not the expected result:

```
echo "0x82BE" | ascii2uni -a X | nkf -S
Result is: 1 token converted
闃セ
```

I [found this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/313032/how-to-convert-a-text-file-from-shift-jis-to-utf-8-and-back-from-the-terminal) that suggests using [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) but ended up with the same results using that method?

Can you folks help?

Comment: I found http://superuser.com/questions/313032/how-to-convert-a-text-file-from-shift-jis-to-utf-8-and-back-from-the-terminal but I found the same result with their method.

Comment: That `iconv` recipe should have converted Shift-JIS to UTF-8. Did it display as 闃セ? What terminal program are you using?

Comment: Disregard, it's not the terminal encoding. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12286/30848), [`recode`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/recode) works cleanly for me on Ubuntu 12.04.5 (LTS):

```
echo -n 0x82ae | recode SHIFT-JIS/x4..UTF-8
```

Of course this converts the output of the the hexadecimal code from Shift-JIS to UTF-8, but heck… UTF-8 is what all the kids are using nowadays. But you can just lop off the `..UTF-8` stuff like this and the output should be pure Shift-JIS:

```
echo -n 0x82ae | recode SHIFT-JIS/x4
```

To confirm it converted to UTF-8 correctly you can pipe it to [`xxd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) like this:

```
echo -n 0x82ae | recode SHIFT-JIS/x4..UTF-8 | xxd -p -u
```

And it checks out as being `E38190` which matches [the exact same character in UTF-8 as shown here](http://unicode-table.com/en/3050/). A full table of Shift-JIS to UTF-8 conversion mappings [can be found here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT).

Or you can just run `xxd` from the command line like this to get the exact hexadecimal code for any character—or series of characters—you wish:

```
echo -n "ぐ" | xxd -p -u
```

Comment: The `iconv` should have converted to UFT-8 as well. I suspect his terminal is using another encoding.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. Writing up the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Your file doesn't contain the binary you think it does. `ascii2uni`
isn't encoding the way you expect it to; I'm not sure why.

```
echo "0x82BE" | ascii2uni -a X > test1
od -tx1 test1
0000000 e8 8a be 0a
```

(Note that `echo -n` does the same thing. The newline `0a` is coming
from `ascii2uni`, not `echo`.)

Converting this with `iconv`:

```
iconv -f SHIFT-JIS -t UTF-8 test1 > test2
od -tx1 test2
0000000 e9 97 83 ef bd be 0a
cat test2
闃ｾ
```

Which is what you got. (Note also that in your ascii2uni example, you
had `82BE`, which is だ in Shift-JIS, instead of your original `0x82ae`,
which is ぐ. I'll stick with `82BE`.)

The problem is that the binary wasn't right to begin with. Do it this way:

```
echo -en '\x82\xbe' > test3
od -tx1 test3
0000000 82 be
iconv -f SHIFT-JIS -t UTF-8 test3 > test4
od -tx1 test4
0000000 e3 81 a0
cat test4
だ
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!